# CakePHP: How to use PHP to dynamically use a CSS property type in an MVC framework

Tags: php, css, cakephp, layout

I would like to make it so the property type `id="current"` will be used when a user is on the page `index`. It will be used if user is on `about`... and so on. I suspect some PHP logic programming needed, can someone offer the code that does that? Or is it something else?..

```
<div  id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li id="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you could send some data to your view (in the data array), which you would then use to change the id on the HTML element, for your CSS to modify?

Comment: I don't quite get it. No the `id="current"` property is already been set in my CSS file. I just need to change the default layout we normally use in CakePHP so that it changes to id=current when a page is on Home...or wherever the user currently is.

Comment: I understand that - so when you call your View from your controller, you need to send some data along with that view call, this will enable you to put some logic in your View to conditionally display the id='Current' when required.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/view/979/set - you need to use the set() method, when you have used the set method to send the data to the view you can then use and manipulate it however you need to.

Comment: Hi I know I can set in my controller but how about the home page? default layout? if you don't mind, could you leave a sample of how it should be? thanks..

Comment: Well your view would have a default css "active" class set to the "Home" nav button / link. So where you recieve data from somewhere that is not "Home" then you remove the class from the "Home" link - and add whereever relevant!?

Comment: setting in view? I heard it is not a good practice. I'm not sure about your explanation. Can you write the sample code??

Comment: if I removed the class as you mentioned where data coming from wherever not home, I'd face error undefined variable for home. when loading homepage. the rest of the pages are working though.

Comment: if(isset(var)) - is probably what you need to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution.

Use an if statement to check if the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable is the page you want (e.g. about) or for a better solution when working with CakePHP, check if controller you want or method matches.

I would go with the second one as you will probably be more accurate.

Comment: Hi, use $this->params['controller'] in your view to get the controller name, and $this->params['action'] to get the action name. Example (I am assuming you have the about as an action):
echo ($this->params['action'] == 'about') ? ' id="current"' : '';